# Integral by parts

Tags: integration

I have the equation:

$$\int -e^{-2t} g(t)dt.$$

$$u = -e^{-2t}$$
$$du = 2e^{-2t}$$
$$dv = g(t)dt$$
$$v= \int g(t)dt$$

I'm trying to get a generalized equation from this indefinite integral but am getting no where. What I have so far is:

$$-e^{-2t}\int g(t)dt - \int 2e^{-2t}\left(\int g(t)dt\right) dt$$

Btw, I need to get a generalized equation to get a particular solution for a higher order different equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of u = $-e^{-2t}$, try u = g(t). With that path, you can use a neat little trick to integrate. Hint: you will need to integrate by parts *twice*

Comment: Ahhhh! So much better :) Thanks